# Using static query with data from a plugin in component in Gatsby

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I'm new to React and Gatsby.
I'm trying to get data from a gatsby csv plugin in a component.
I read that in components you have to use static query to get data but I can't make it works. I received "Cannot read property 'props' of undefined", so I think that I'm doing something wrong with the data constructor or maybe the syntax is wrong.

```
import React from 'react';
import { StaticQuery, graphql } from "gatsby"

const data = this.props.data.allLettersCsv.edges

export default () => (
  <StaticQuery
    query={graphql`
      query Corrispondences {
        allLettersCsv {
          edges {
            node {
              word
              value
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `}
    render={data.map((row,i) => (
        <div>
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Letter</th>
              <th>ASCII Value</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
              <tr key={`${row.node.value} ${i}`}>
                <td>{row.node.word}</td>
                <td>{row.node.value}</td>
              </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      ))
    }
  />
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 problems in your code:

First, you are declaring data outside of component:

```
const data = this.props.data.allLettersCsv.edges
```

There is probably no `this.props` in the module scope, hence the error you get. You should remove this line, since gatsby provides graphql query results to your component via `StaticQuery`’s `render`.

Second, `StaticQuery`'s `render` expect a function, where it passes the results from your graphql query as `data` (Checkout React's [docs on render props](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html)).

So you could re-write it like this for example:

```
render={data => (
  <>
    {data.allLettersCsv.edges.map((row,i) => ...)}
  </>
)
```

Hope it helps!